# Multi Line line graph matplotlib

Tags: python, csv, plot, graph, line

I am trying to graph 3 datasets of the same type onto one linegraph with three different lines. All datasets share the same x type, 'time' and y type, 'measurement'. However, the lengths of each dataset are different for both the x and y types within each dataset. How would I go about creating a three-line line graph using matplotlib?

Each data set is extracted from a csv file, and ends up in the form of a list. This goes for both the x and y components of each dataset. Here is how I gather my data:

```
# Data Set 1
with open('File1.csv', 'r') as f:
     data_1 = list(reader(f))

measurement_1 = [i[3] for i in data_1[1::]]
time_1 = [parser.parse(i[0]) for i in data_1[1::]]

measurement_1, time_1 = zip(*[(i, j) for i, j in zip(measurement_1, time_1) if i !=''])

measurement_1 = list(measurement_1)
time_1 = list(time_1)

# Data Set 2
with open('File2.csv', 'r') as f:
     data_2 = list(reader(f))

measurement_2 = [i[3] for i in data_2[1::]]
time_2 = [parser.parse(i[0]) for i in data_2[1::]]

measurement_2, time_2 = zip(*[(i, j) for i, j in zip(measurement_2, time_2) if i !=''])

measurement_2 = list(measurement_2)
time_2 = list(time_2)

# Data Set 3
with open('File3.csv', 'r') as f:
     data_3 = list(reader(f))

measurement_3 = [i[3] for i in data_3[1::]]
time_3 = [parser.parse(i[0]) for i in data_3[1::]]

measurement_3, time_3 = zip(*[(i, j) for i, j in zip(measurement_3, time_3) if i !=''])

measurement_3 = list(measurement_3)
time_3 = list(time_3)
```

Comment: Plot each dataset's x and y values: ```plt.plot(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3)```.

Comment: @wwii thanks, didn't think it'd be as trivial as that considering that the data sets were of massively different lengths. but it works perfectly. thank you! :)

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided the reference dataframes, here is a broad framework.

```
ax = df.plot()
df2.plot(ax = ax)
df3.plot(ax = ax)

plt.show()
```